# Cannot open database "ContosoUniversity1" requested by the login

Tags: sql, asp.net

Cannot open database "ContosoUniversity1" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user

What I need to do?

Comment: We can't possibly know unless you provide more information. Can you connect to the database from other applications (say, management studio if we are talking SQL Server) using the same credentials?

Comment: Where did you get the database from and how did it end up on your database instance? Did you download and restore it or construct it with scripts?

Does the login that you are attempting to use exist as a database server login (assuming this is Microsoft SQL Server)? Does it exist as a user for the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to fix it

Open the "Developer Command Propmpt for VisualStudio" under your start/programs menu. Run the following commands:

sqllocaldb.exe stop v11.0

sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0